Настройка запуска - Параметры командной строки в qt

Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем нужны эти параметры и как их используют (параметры командной строки).
Никогда не пользовался.

argv в int main(int argc, char** argv)

Вообще это достаточно базовый вопрос на который можно найти ответ.
Есть такое понятие - точка входа в приложение. Она определена заранее
int main(){
//ваш код
}

был приведен пример без параметров можно и с параметрами(как в любой функции)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])


argc -число параметров(argument count)
argv - это сами параметры  в виде набора строк(argument value)

Если вы введете параметры командной строки, то они передадутся в точку входа именно в эти переменные, стоит заметить, что argc[0] - там хранится путь в исполняемому файлу .exe.
Вы должны понимать, что "под капотом" программа билдится и вызывается через командную строку с разными параметрами. Вы можете лучше разобраться есть попробуете сами запустить вашу программу через консоль. Так же можете попробовать поработать в VS code там придется все делать вручную, зато сможете разобраться.
